# Haskell optimizing infinite list implementation

Tags: list, haskell, optimization, infinite

My code gives the wanted result but I wonder if there is a better way to code this. This is the given example:

```
pair [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , ... ]
[ [ 1 , 2 ] , [ 3 , 4 ] , [ 5 , 6 ] , ... ]
```

and the given code:

```
pair::[a] -> [[a]]
pair =
```

My solution:

```
pair :: [a] -> [[a]]
pair (x:y:xs) = ((x:y:[]):[]) ++ pair xs
```

Comment: Never concatenate lists if you can use `:`: `++` works in *O(n)* (with *n* the size of the first list) whereas `:` works in *O(1)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But if the size of the first list is *O(1)* as in any case were you can easily replace `(++)` with `(:)` then `(++)` is also *O(1)*. So while `(:)` may be a constant factor faster than `(++)` asymptotically they are the same.

Comment: You didn't state a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the cons operator `:` will be much more performant than concatenating lists:

```hs
pair :: [a] -> [[a]]
pair (x:y:xs) = [x, y] : pair xs
```

The reasoning is that lists in Haskell are linked lists where each item points to the next until the end of the list. Pushes and Pops are cheap when done at the head of the list because you are only pointing the head at the head of an existing list.

When you concatenate two linked list, you are essentially rebuilding the complete first list so that its last element can point at the first element of the second list.

The performance gain is minor in your example since you only have two elements in your list, but as a general rule, if you're dealing with operations on the head of the list, it's almost always going to be more performant to use cons.

Comment: Did you test this assertion? In my tests, GHC emits the exact same core for both implementations.

Comment: I have not tested the compiled GHC. If it is able to optimize in this specific case, that's pretty cool and I can update my answer, but I think the general rule holds and we shouldn't code `++` when `:` will suffice and is, at least theoretically, more performant.